# Adding Squared Elements of an Arraylist to said Arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to add the squared elements for back into the original arraylist. For example [1,2,3] should become [1, 1, 2, 4, 3, 9]. My issue is I am not sure if my machine is just bad because I am getting an out of  memory error. Here is my attempt. The recursive call is just to get the sum of the arraylist.

```
public static int sumOfSquares(List<Integer> num) {


    if (num.isEmpty()) {
        return 0;
    }
    for(int i=0; i<num.size();i++){
        int hold= num.get(i)*num.get(i);
        num.add(hold);
    }


    return num.get(0) + sumOfSquares(num.subList(1, num.size()));
}
```

Comment: Your `for` loop is an infinite loop because it's adding to `num`, which increases the `size()` which causes the loop to never end.

Comment: would a for each loop be better?

Comment: You probably shouldn't do that. Why mutate the list just to get the sum of the squares? If you need that, separate the steps.

Comment: @EricSmith No, that would have the same issue (In fact, I think it would throw an exception since it doesn't permit you to mutate the list as you iterate over it). Your code seems to be doing two things at once. Separate the squaring from the summing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your implementation is that it does not distinguish original numbers from the squares that you have previously added.

First, since you are doing this recursively, you don't need a `for` loop. Each invocation needs to take care of the initial value of the list alone.

Next, `add(n)` adds the number at the end, while your example shows adding numbers immediately after the original value. Therefore, you should use `num.add(1, hold)`, and skip two initial numbers when making a recursive call.

Here is how the fixed method should look:

```
public static int sumOfSquares(List<Integer> num) {
    if (num.isEmpty()) {
        return 0;
    }
    // Deal with only the initial element
    int hold= num.get(0)*num.get(0);
    // Insert at position 1, right after the squared number
    num.add(1, hold);
    // Truncate two initial numbers, the value and its square:
    return num.get(1) + sumOfSquares(num.subList(2, num.size()));
}
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/ByylCV)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to safely add (or remove) elements to a list while iterating it:

1. Iterate backwards over the list, so that the indexes of the upcoming elements don't shift.
2. Use an [`Iterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) or [`ListIterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html).

You can fix your code using either strategy, but I recommend a `ListIterator` for readable code.

```
import java.util.ListIterator;

public static void insertSquares(List<Integer> num) {
    ListIterator<Integer> iter = num.listIterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        int value = iter.next();
        iter.add(value * value);
    }
}
```

Then, move the summing code into a separate method so that the recursion doesn't interfere with the inserting of squares into the list. Your recursive solution will work, but an iterative solution would be more efficient for Java.